# Regular *negative* spikes in neural network training loss

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, stochastic-gradient-descent

I am training an [ALL-CNN network](https://github.com/mateuszbuda/ALL-CNN) using the Adam solver. As the figure shows, the testing seems to converge to an acceptable solution, but there are these regular negative spikes during training that leave me thinking I can do better. Is that so, or has anybody seen similar behavior?
[image: Adam training of ALL-CNN]

Comment: Are you recording the loss after each batch? Maybe it is a specific batch in which weird data is contained?

Comment: after each batch. But I thought that the (mini-)batches are picked at random. No?

Comment: you mean the ordering of the batches? Usually it is randomized in the beginning, but then it is the same order for each epoch. But that also depends on your own implementation

Comment: I mean just a guess into the blue, but could it be that you average the loss per batch. 

loss/batchsize

but maybe your last batch has fewer samples and you still divide the loss by the same original batchsize, causing a sudden drop in the loss.

Comment: good point, loss is averaged per mini-batch. But the loss-drop is actually quasi-periodic, with drops occuring mostly every 800, sometimes every 700 iterations. So it doesn't seem to be sample size.

Comment: and you are not using a learning rate scheduler?

Maybe just track each loss and batch, and maybe you can identify a pattern in the batches that cause the drop

Comment: I'll try tracking each batch, thx. The lr policy is polynomial decay, as described [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L157-L170).